# Slow PHP and interpreting XDebug profiler data

Tags: php, performance, debugging, profiling, phpstorm

I've just begun using XDebug + PHPStorm today to help debug a slow page on my app. Attached is the profiler data.

Am I interpreting correctly that 1,044 calls to `number_format()` are taking 116.5 seconds? 0.10 seconds per call? That seems extremely slow for a native PHP function.

Other calls are performing slowly too, 1,619 calls to `abs()` taking 254.8 seconds (0.15 seconds per call).

[image: PHPStorm Xdebug Profiler Data]

This is my first attempt at profiling, what is a good way to approach improving my code to fix these load times? I'm running WAMP, for what it's worth.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you sure *Time* is in seconds? Either way, yes, these are your longest calls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Yes, the time column is in milliseconds. Any idea how native PHP calls can be so slow? Is it perhaps a hardware issue?

Comment: *"`abs()` taking 254.8 seconds"* -- are you running it on some prehistoric Pentium MMX or something? If not -- then most likely time is in `ms` or even `us`. But yes -- it takes that percentage of time (according to your screenshot)

Comment: `abs()` isn't taking that long, __1,619__ calls to `abs()` is taking that long.... that's a lot of calls to `abs()`... likewise 1,044 calls to `number_format()` and 1,151 calls to `strtotime()`... take a closer look at where all those calls are being made (probably in a loop), are they all really necessary?

Comment: Thanks for you reply @MarkBaker! Still, wouldn't 0.15 seconds (on average) for a single `abs()` be slow?

Comment: 0.15 seconds would be slow under normal circumstances, but you're running with xdebug enabled, which adds overhead.... what's important isn't the actual time here, it's the proportion of overall time..... without xdebug, it would be faster, but that 53% of the execution time being taken up calling abs() with xdebug enabled will still be 53% of execution time being taken up calling abs() without xdebug

Comment: @MarkBaker I was able to considerably reduce the load time by moving a lot of the formatting to the data layer (moving abs() from PHP to the mysql select, for instance). Your comment put me on the right track, so if you submit an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!